# Names not resolved with DNS over VPN on Win10

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

For a couple of months now, when connecting via OpenVPN, resolving hostnames that are on the remote network has not worked for me (but servers work by IP address).

When I run nslookup with the hostname I get the correct IP address of the first DNS server in the VPN, but it is recognized as `Server: UnKnown`. And I also get the information: `*** UnKnown can't find <host_name>: Non-existent domain`

Nslookup to the same host from another computer on my network (which is running Windows 7) shows the same DNS server IP address in VPN, but also recognizes its correct name: `Server: <server_DNS name>`. On this computer the names are resolved correctly. The OpenVPN client configuration is the same.

I tried on Windows 10 to add these lines to the OpenVPN configuration:

```
register-dns
pull
block-outside-dns
```

But that didn't help.

I can't find the cause, could you please help?

Comment: Add `dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8` in your OpenVPN configuration to set DNS server to use.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/637579/setting-dns-servers-using-openvpn-client-config-file